# Probability to get at least one 6 and at least one 5 in 10 rolls of a die

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Probability to get at least one 6 and at least one 5 in 10 rolls of a die

I came up across this question and my answer to this was $1 - (4/6)^{10}$ (i.e. $1 $- probability that no $6$ and no $5$ appears)

However the answer given is $$1 - 2~ (5/6)^{10} + (2/3)^{10} ~~~~\text{(how ?)}$$

Is my interpretation of **NOT$($at least one $6$ and at least one $5) =$ No $6$ and No $5$** wrong ?

Should it be **No $6$ or No $5$** instead ?
(DeMorgan's Law need to be applied here ?)

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is not always correct. There could be one six and no fives, and the equation would evaluate to be true = false

Comment: That indeed seemed to be the case. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the issue is with your interpretation of the opposite of "at least one five and at least one six." The opposite of this should be "no five OR no six" (because of De Morgan's Law, as you note). This is a somewhat complicated event which could be approached via inclusion/exclusion, for instance:

$$\mathbb P(\text{no five or no six}) = \mathbb P(\text{no five}) + \mathbb P(\text{no six}) - \mathbb P(\text{no five and no six})$$

This formulation of the problem will point you in the direction of the answer you cited, but there are (as nearly always with probability problems) other ways you could approach this.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This cleared out my doubt (I upvoted btw, due to no rep it doesn't show up I guess)